# How can I put nav higher than it is using float and clear?

Tags: html, css

[The structure I need to recreate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eE6kB.png)

I need to put the bottom right rectangle below the blue square just like on the left side and I have trouble with it. I have to use *float*  and *clear*. Currently it is too low. Only the shape matters.

```css
.blok1_1 {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  width: 450px;
  height: 330px;
  float: left;
}

.blok1_2 {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  width: 362px;
  height: 330px;
  float: right;
  clear: right;
}

.blok1_3 {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 1075px;
  height: 855px;
  float: right;
}

.blok1_4 {
  background-color: mediumspringgreen;
  width: 450px;
  height: 520px;
  float: left;
}

.blok1_5 {
  background-color: mediumspringgreen;
  width: 360px;
  height: 525px;
  float: right;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<nav class="blok1_1">
</nav>
<nav class="blok1_2">
</nav>
<section class="blok1_3">
</section>
<nav class="blok1_4">
</nav>
<nav class="blok1_5">
</nav>
```

Comment: Given that you need to use `float` and `clear` as opposed to `flex`, `grid`, or `columns`, Does the HTML need to be identical or can the elements be rearranged and/or use wrapper elements?

Comment: Html can be little different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

easiest way is to use flex

```css
#container{
   display:flex;
   margin:0 auto;
   justify-content:center;
}

.end{
   display:flex;
   flex-direction:column;
}

.top{
   width:150px;
   height:200px;
   background-color:lightblue;
}

.bot{
   width:150px;
   height:400px;
   background-color:green;
}
 
#middle{
   width:150px;
   height:600px;
   background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div class='end'>
    <div class='top'></div>
    <div class='bot'></div>
  </div>
  <div id='middle'>
  </div>
   <div class='end'>
    <div class='top'></div>
    <div class='bot'></div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

So I assume this is an exercise with pretty specific requirements. In that case I don't think DCR's answer will suffice, altough I have to say that it would probably be the real-world solution these days. Especially the part where floats are replaced with flex and the html structure is changed in some grid like construction of a left, middle and right section. I fully believe that's the way to go.

BUT since it's an exercise and using float and clear are your only options. Have a look at the code below!

- Use a container for the 4 square elements.
   (the yellow part in the middle is just the background from the container)
- The left elements float left and the right elements float right.
- Since you want the bottom squares to be below the top squares instead of next to them you also add the clear left or right rule to these elements.

```css
.container {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 350px;
  height: 300px;
}


.left-top {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
}


.right-top{
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: right;
}


.left-bottom {
  background-color: mediumspringgreen;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}


.right-bottom {
  background-color: mediumspringgreen;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  float: right;
  clear: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-top"></div>
  <div class="right-top"></div>

  <div class="left-bottom"></div>
  <div class="right-bottom"></div>
</div>
```